# Applying arithmetic operators to list elements in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
string="hi how are you"
s =string.split()
print(s)
for i in range(len(s)):
    print(s[i])
    s += s[i]
print(s)
```

I just began learning python and I noticed something weird which didn't make sense to me.

So when I do `s += s[i]` shouldn't I be getting something like this 
`['hi', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'hi', 'how', 'are', 'you']`

but instead I'm getting something like this: `['hi', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'h', 'i', 'h', 'o', 'w', 'a', 'r', 'e', 'y', 'o', 'u']`.

why do the individual letters get added?

I know we can obtain this `['hi', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'hi', 'how', 'are', 'you']` using the append function but isn't **+** supposed to do the same thing ?

Comment: The `+` operation on lists is equivalent to `extend`, not `append`. Just as doing `[1] + [2, 3]` will result in `[1, 2, 3]` and not `[1, [2,3]]`

Comment: okay. This makes sense but in what scenario would we have to use extend() function when the + operator could do the same thing

Comment: A few reasons that are hard to list all here. Feel free to search for more details: `extend` is an instance method that work on a list in-place and does not return a new list; handles with type mismatch better, for example: `[1,2] +"34"` raises an error while `[1,2].extend("34")` works just fine

Comment: thank you. so much for the clarification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `+=` operator for lists doesn't append an element to a list, it concatenates two lists. for example:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [2, 3, 4]
>>> a += b # will give you [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4]
```

Now, if we try to use `+` operator for appending an **element** it will throw an exception

```
>>> a += 2
```

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

---

Now let's come to your case. The string is interpreted as a list of characters, that's why 
the operation you try to do is viewed as concatenating a list with a list of chars.

```
>>> a = [] 
>>> a += "hello"
>>> a

['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

Comment: A better wording for `list of characters` would be a sequence. see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) under the `extend` operation

Answer (score 0):

Actually no, the actual output is fine, this is why.

when you try to add "hi" to ['hi', 'how', 'are', 'you'], you are trying to add a string to a list of strings. This should be an error. But actually strings are already a list of characters. What you are doing is that you are effectively adding lists to lists, hence  ['hi', 'how', 'are', 'you'] get combined with each letter in "Hi"

What you want to do can either be achieved by `s.append(s[i])` or by `s += [s[i]]`